# How to Make Retrofit Method Get Without Parameter?

Tags: android, methods, retrofit

i want Get Data with retrofit and i have problem, i will expain with code

```
ApiService.class :
public interface ApiService {

@GET
Call<ResponseBody> artikel();
}
```

and my procces class

```
Call<ResponseBody> get_artikel;
    Retrofit retrofit;
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Status.HOST_ARTICLE + "content/" + list.get(conversationQueue).conversationId + "/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient)
            .build();


    ApiService apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
    get_artikel = apiService.artikel();
```

if like that, i got error

> Missing either @GET URL or @Url parameter.

i know in ApiService i must make Parameter "/content/" in Get, but i need make it in proccess class like this

> baseUrl(Status.HOST_ARTICLE + "content/" + list.get(conversationQueue).conversationId + "/")

what the best solution for this?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried @GET("./") ? taken from https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1567#issuecomment-180115150

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(Status.HOST_ARTICLE + "/" )
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(httpClient)
        .build();
```

And

```
public interface ApiService {

     @GET("content/{conversationId}" ) 
     Call<ResponseBody> artikel(@Path("conversationId") String conversationId);
}
```

Then

```
apiService.artikel(list.get(conversationQueue).conversationId) ;
```

Comment: Question is how to make a `GET` without params, not with.

Comment: @FlorescuGeorgeCătălin this is what he actually wanted to do, considering that he seems to instantiate a new Retrofit and a new Service, per api call. But it would be `@GET(" ")`

Comment: It can be `@GET Call<ResponseBody> artikel(@Url String url);` to match his initial need.

Comment: FlorescuGeorgeCătălin sir where i can read documentation about retrofit ? i tried to search i can't found to explain about symbol { } or function @Path , thank you